# Unable to run spark-shell from bin

Tags: linux, apache-spark, environment-variables

I'm new to spark, I downloaded precompiled spark.

When I try to run spark-shell from **bin** folder on command line, it returns

> `:cd /users/denver/spark-1.6/bin`
>       `:spark-shell`
>
> command not found

But if I run it like

> `:cd /users/denver/spark-1.6`
>     `:./bin/spark-shell`

it launches spark ..

can you please let me know why it is throwing error in the 1st case

Comment: do you run it in Windows or in Linux?

Comment: am running it on mac .

Comment: how did you run the `spark-shell` in first case?

Comment: can you please check the edit made to question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why you can not run the `spark-shell` command in first case is because of [`environment variable`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)

The terminal searches for executables in `$PATH`. This is a Unix environment variable that lists directories containing system binaries (such as **ls**, **echo**, or **gcc**). If you call an executable that's not in a `$PATH` directory (such as `spark-shell`), you need to indicate its absolute path in the file system.

In the terminal `.` is a synonym for the current working directory, thus `./bin/spark-shell` can work properly. You could equally well call `./some/path/bin/spark-shell`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: As a direct solution to the question's first case, try running `./spark-shell` instead of `spark-shell`

Comment: If instead of `./bin/spark-shell`, I want `bash-profile` to work, what changes does the OP need to do in the environmental variable?

Answer (score 1):

In linux:

Add to your ~/.bashrc

export SPARK_HOME=/home/das/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin

Source ~/.bashrc.
Relaunch terminal
then spark-shell works from anywhere
If it doesn't work add to ~/.profile

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. Using `./bin/spark-shell` after changing to the spark directory should solve the issue.